# Possible to use a processor #if on a static/const member?

Tags: c#

I have a class in my project which holds global configuration, as follows:

```
public class Config {
    public const bool LOGGING_ENABLED = false;
}
```

I want to then be able to use that member to write a preprocessor directive, like the following:

```
#if LOGGING_ENABLED
    [Logging]
    public class MyClass: ContextBoundObject
#else
    public class MyClass
#endif
    {
        ...
    }
```

But clearly, `LOGGING_ENABLED` will come as undefined since it is not actually referencing Config.LOGGING_ENABLED.  Is there any way to reference constant members in another class?  I don't want to have to put `#define LOGGING_ENABLED` at the top of every class file, that defeats the whole purpose of this.

Comment: Have you thought about defining a compile time constant LOGGING_ENABLED which in turn controls the value of Config.LOGGING_ENABLED?

Comment: @IanNewson: but `LOGGING_ENABLED` _is_ a compile time constant.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, I mean compilation constant as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76zdzba1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to write an interceptor really, have you considered using interception or just dependency injecting the logger (you can inject a noop logger when you want to turn off logging)

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. The C# preprocessor is a C# construct. All it's instructions are "executed" by the C# compiler. The runtime does not know what `#if` directives you used.

In order to dynamically change the attributes on a type you'd need an assembly rewriting build step after the C# compiler is done. This has quite a few drawbacks.

Find a different approach. For example, define `LOGGING_ENABLED` as a [preprocessor symbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76zdzba1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (using the project settings).

That said, I advise against this approach entirely. You'll have a hard time testing your app if the code you test is not the code that runs in production. Use the same code in all build situations as much as possible. That can mean that you need to make runtime decisions. For example you might have different loggers and pick one at app startup.

Comment: I agree with advising against this approach entirely, but I am not sure what you mean with the "Use static code" advice.

Comment: @MikeNakis yeah that statement was really vague. Clarified.

Comment: Your answer now is the most complete.

Comment: @MikeNakis how could I disagree with that? :)

Comment: Can I set the pre-processor symbol at the solution level, somehow?  I would hate to go to each project and manually do this.

Comment: @gnychis not that I know of but you probably can edit the csproj files to include some common settings from a solution-level file. I'm quite sure MSBuild can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to add `#define LOGGING_ENABLED` to the top of every class file, you can just add it to your project options/settings/properties, so it will be available during the compilation of every class file of yours.

Comment: That's not how you use `#define` in C#. `#define` just takes a name, not a definition. (And in other languages where `#define` does take a definition, you wouldn't generally want `=` to be part of that definition.)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, better now?

Comment: The main "bummer" here is that this doesn't seem to propagate across references.  So for example, I have Config.cs (which is like my global configuration) in a project with some other global things.  I have a second project which references it.  If I put "#define LOGGING_ENABLED" at the top of Config.cs, it is not within scope of the project that references it.

Comment: Yes, I know.  The entire approach has issues.  I would recommend that you follow the advise given by @usr in the last paragraph of his answer.  Also, the `System.Diagnostics.Conditional` attribute mentioned by Mark Shevchenko will be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

C#-ways to do it are:

1. Create 2 separate implementation of the same interface: first with logging, and second without it. Choose an implementation at run-time, checking the value of `LOGGING_ENABLED`.
2. Use the `System.Diagnostics.Conditional` attribute.